# How to customise UIAction Sheet in iOS 8

Tags: ios, uiactionsheet

suggest me , How to customise `UIActionSheet` in iOS 8

it crashes in iOS8 using the code

```
[[[actionSheeet valueForKey:@"_buttons"] objectAtIndex:0] 
setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pathForMailicon] 
forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS8 you should not be using `UIActionSheet` at all. Instead you should be using [`UIAlertController`](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html).

This has replaced both `UIActionSheet` and `UIAlertView`.

As for customising. I'm not sure that you can put images into them? If you want images and stuff I'd recommend creating a custom view from scratch.